# Controller.OnException is called but returns error 500,only in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, http-error

I'm having a strange behaviour in my Asp.Net MVC application. I have overriden OnException method in my controller to handle errors:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    var type = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
    var httpMethod = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

    var returnType = GetReturnType(type, action, httpMethod);
    if (returnType == typeof(JsonResult))
        filterContext.Result = HandleJsonError(filterContext.Exception);
    else
        filterContext.Result = HandleError(filterContext.Exception);
}
```

The code above identify if the method called is a normal view result or a jsonResult, and show a error page or return the error message in json. If its Json, it returns something like that:

```
{"OK":false,"ErrorMessage":"Error message to the user"}
```

So, when an error occurrs, the browser receives a HTTP 200 code, like there was no error, but in my client code I identify the error message and show it to the user.

This is working fine on my development environment, but when I uploaded it to production, the async request is returning a HTTP 500 error, but the returned content is still the same JSON. That means that OnException is still called, but returns a 500 code instead of 200. How can i make it reuturn 200 on the production?

Comment: Did you try add some log in OnException method?

Comment: No, but i know its beeing called because of the content returned, its generated on this method.